# How to bind to "self" in WinJS

Tags: windows-8, winjs

When I'm using the default data binding in WinJS, how do I bind to the "current item" instead of specifying a property to bind to. I'm think of the "." in XAML that binds to the current item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "this" on the right side of the binding expression:

`data-win-bind="innerText: this myInitializer"`

However, if you do so, you should write a custom initializer that knows how to pull apart "this" into something that correctly turns into a string.

Comment: Tremendous. I don't know why I didn't think about trying that.

Comment: @Chris: Interested to know where you found that out. Is it mentioned anywhere in the docs?

Comment: I must confess - I was on the WinJS team until today, and was the PM on the data binding stuff. I'll pass a note to our doc people to make sure this gets reflected in the docs in a more obvious way.

Comment: instead of an initializer one could also override `toString()` of the object.
As for the docs: Has this been documented anywhere in the meantime?